# Нужно ли это тире в этом предложении? Помогите разобраться

Tags: пунктуация, тире, двоеточие, тире-или-двоеточие

Пожалуйста, поясните: можно и нужно ли в моём предложении ставить тире? Если нет, то что там надо поставить?

*Я полагаю, Вы выбираете второй вариант: найти  человека, который Вас поддержит, [—] да?*

И ещё: как я понимаю, в этом же предложении можно всю конструкцию выделить с помощью двух тире, но если я, как в этом примере, её выделяю с помощью двоеточия, то это правильно тоже?
Спасибо Вам.

Comment: Двоеточие, если что-то новое, например новая формулировка варианта.

Answer (score 1):

**Предлагаю вариант** (самая простая расстановка знаков):

*Я полагаю, Вы выбираете второй вариант: найти человека, который Вас поддержит, да?*

**Пояснение**

Сложное предложение из **двух блоков**.

Бессоюзная связь обозначена **двоеточием** (какой именно).

Частица ДА в функции отдельного **предложения**, бессоюзная связь.

Answer (score 0):

### В данном случае действует правило постановки тире при поясняющих членах предложения, поэтому предложение должно выглядеть так:

"Я полагаю, вы выбираете второй вариант (*а именно, то есть какой вариант*) — найти человека, который вас поддержит". В данном случае "найти" нужно рассматривать как несогласованное определение.

> Правило: "Перед пояснительным членом предложения обычно стоят слова именно, а именно, то есть (при их отсутствии в предложении эти слова могут быть вставлены): Она была воспитана no-старинному,  то есть окружена мамушками, нянюшками, подружками и сенными девушками". Как показывают некоторые из приведенных примеров, вместо запятой перед пояснительным членом предложения (при отсутствии пояснительного союза) часто ставится тире".

---

P.S. Лично мне ближе модифицированное предложение с очевидной основой второй части предложения:

> "Я полагаю, вы выбираете второй вариант (а именно, то есть): [вы хотите найти] человека,
> который Вас поддержит" (здесь бессоюзное сложное предложение со
> значением пояснения между частями, в таком случае должно ставиться
> двоеточие).

Comment: А куда вы "*да?*" дели?

Comment: Частицу "да" я бы вынес в отдельное новое предложение: "Да?"

Comment: Дело в том, что нельзя изменять исходный пример, если он корректен. Представьте, что это задание и есть только возможность расставить знаки. Тем более что о знаке перед этим фрагментом в шапке спрашивается.

Comment: Про стык знаков в правилах, которыми я руководствуюсь, ничего не сказано, поэтому не хочу вводить автора в заблуждение.

Comment: @Oleed, знаки препинания  в большинстве случаях прежде всего зависят от структуры предложения. Это один из ведущих принципов русской пунктуации.

Comment: @Серж При чём здесь это? Это как "2 + 2 = 4".

Answer (score 0):

Я бы оформила предложение с двумя тире: со вставной конструкцией и симметрией знаков.

*Я полагаю, Вы выбираете второй вариант, — найти человека, который Вас поддержит, — да?*

[Вставные предложения и словосочетания](http://old-rozental.ru/punctuatio.php?sid=123#pp123)

Comment: Симметрия знаков нормой не является.

Comment: @Римма Михайлова, нет неудачна вставная конструкция.

Answer (score 0):

Да, все знаки препинания в Вашем предложении верны, и тире тоже обязательно. Двоеточие стоит верно, об этом уже сказал человек сверху, он прав. А тире стоит потому, что нужно закрыть придаточное предложение, стоящее после двоеточия. А частица **ДА** относится к главной части предложения.